# Is there a way to specify where within index.html the `ng build` files are output to?

Tags: angular

Running `ng build` creates the following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <app></app>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/runtime.09b569c0ccb2e6f4674d.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/polyfills.f2bc2612562878ce4ca1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/main.a0c64004d4c4f3d21210.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I want the scripts to be put into the `head` with a `defer` attribute, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/runtime.09b569c0ccb2e6f4674d.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/polyfills.f2bc2612562878ce4ca1.js"></script>
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/public/client/main.a0c64004d4c4f3d21210.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app></app>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible to do within Angular without writing my own customs script?

Comment: This might be one of those situations where you’ll have to eject and customize the webpack portion of the process with a plug-in.

Comment: Can't be bothered doing that now, it will mess with backwards compatibility. I managed to solve this by just modifying the post-`ng build` bundle in my server and concatenating the other scripts together, removing them from the HTML, and appending a new script to the end of the `head`. I do that on startup in my server so it's a quick operation and doesn't affect the UX.